# Is moderating X grammatical?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> The company started moderating the character names of the video game
> as kids started using slurs when choosing their characters' names.

Is "moderating character names" grammatical? Is it idiomatic? What's a better way of saying this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "moderating character names" is exactly the right term to use in this context.

For web sites, online games, etc, the word **moderate** has a specialised meaning: you can read more about it on this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderation_system). The article defines it as:

> ... monitoring and vetting user-generated content (UGC) for social media platforms of all types, in order to ensure that the content complies with legal and regulatory exigencies, site/community guidelines, user agreements, and that it falls within norms of **taste and acceptability** for that site and its cultural context.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase 'moderating character names' is fine for use here.  It should help to alleviate situations of use of unsavoury names.

From Google Dictionary,

> moderate
> verb
> /ˈmɒdəreɪt/
> 1.
> make or become less extreme, intense, rigorous, or violent.